# Automate sdk versioning and publishing in gitlab CICD

Tags: docker, npm, gitlab, version, cicd

SCENARIO :
We have a product witch has 3 main parts, backend, sdk and frontend.
sdk is developed as a package in a monorepo env alongside backend.
sdk is used by frontend.
sdk is build by the backend guys and published to a private npm repo in our private gitlab server.

we have 3 environments : debug, stage, prod
different features for sdk is developed in different feature branches.

each branch need to move throw a cycles to finish. first we merge the branch into debug branch, here we need to automate the sdk's build and publish process.
This is my current docker file
`RUN cd packages/sdk && npm version patch && npm run build && npm publish --tag debug --verbose`
this works and is ok the sdk is published correctly, BUT the version is not stored anywhere and the next time we run this script it tries to create the same version. I have to manually update the version locally and push it up to be ready for the next time.

QUESTION : how to make this updated version number persist?

I tried pushing the updated code back to the gitlab server. But it did not work and I was told that this is not the best practice .

I was thinking about using a gitlab variables and using the [rest api](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_level_variables.html#update-a-variable) to update it ? But then I should skip the `npm version` and write my own custom script to get the variable from gitlab, change it, run `npm version MY_VERSION` and the use this api to update the stored version?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option: I would completely remove any hard-coded version and use Git tags to tie versions to a software commit. After that you can use the git command in CI to set the variable during build.

For instance you could manually assign version:

> git tag -a   -m "update version" git push -o ci.skip
> --follow-tag

Get version in CI:

> VERSION=$(git tag --points-at $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA)

Set version for build in CI (React):

> npm run build REACT_APP_VERSION=$VERSION

You can also set this version in any of your parts.

Find code and documentation for automated versioning example here:

https://gitlab.com/base58-public/ci/templates/-/blob/main/Jobs/Auto-Versioning.yml
https://base58.hr/en/stories/automated-software-release-versioning